# CSS descendant selector with focus state not working in iOS

Tags: ios, css, focus, tabindex, descendant

I'm using the :focus state to show content, when the parent element has focus. Like so:

```
.child { display: none; }
.parent:focus .child { display: block; }
```

Note that the parent element has **tabindex="0"** set. Is there a way to get this to work in iOS browsers? I'm asking to see if a CSS-only solution is possible, no javascript please.

I've set up a reduced test case fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/E8zCU/

Answer (score 1):

An answer that worked for me for a similar problem is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584335/css-focus-not-working-in-ios)

As the poster in that thread said, you just have to add

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

to the top of your html code.