# CSS :focus Not Working in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I have a box with an image in it. On hover / focus, I want a color overlay and caption to fade in over it. It works perfectly in almost every browser and device except on iOS devices.

I am using both :hover and :focus pseudo-classes to accommodate various devices, but it doesn't seem to help with iOS. Nothing happens when you mouse over.

Here is my code, and I also have a fully functioning [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5d4s5hm/4/).

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.my_image {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.my_image p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
.overlay {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(121, 87, 164, .80);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
.my_image:hover .overlay,
.my_image:hover p,
.my_image:focus .overlay,
.my_image:focus p {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_image">
  <img src="https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1428976365951-b70e0fa5c551?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=225&q=75&w=350" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <p>Overlay Caption</p>
</div>
```

Is there some way I can make this work without JS? I am using jQuery on the page so I'm not totally opposed, I just didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [:active pseudo-class doesn't work in mobile safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution in the [post Sergey Denisov shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885018/active-pseudo-class-doesnt-work-in-mobile-safari) worked. You simply add `ontouchstart=""` to just the body element, and it magically works, like so:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
...
</body>
```

That's it! Couldn't tell you how or why this works, but it does.

Comment: This trick doesn't seem to work anymore in Safari and Chrome on iOS 10.

Answer (score 2):

I added tabindex="0" to the element and it seems to accept focus.

Comment: Very clean solution. Last problem is that focused element doesn't lose focus when you click outside of it.