# Ios input border missing on focus

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari

I have an input with a border that changes colour on focus. This works well on android and web browsers, issues appear on ios. The border disappears altogether when tapping inside the input and writing. Any ideas?

```css
.my-input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.my-input:focus {
  border: 2px solid purple;
  outline: none;
}

.my-input:disabled {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<input class="my-input" type="text">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :focus Not Working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584335/css-focus-not-working-in-ios)

Comment: Try setting `-webkit-appearance:none` and `outline: none` to the `input`. iOS sets some custom styles for inputs which may conflict with your changes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599533/ios-forces-rounded-corners-and-glare-on-inputs

Comment: @elveti you're right, that combined with `outline-width:0` did the trick